# Java : using graphics component within an action listener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I've made a JFrame with Diferent JButtons and i'd like to get an image from another class. Any ideas? Or how draw on the same class but on the action performed?
Because it doesnt let me to do any drawings...my complier always gives me error messages

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class red extends JFrame {

    public JButton b;
    public JButton b1;
    public JButton b2;
    public JButton b3;
    public JButton b4;

    public static Image p;
    public static Graphics g;
    public red() throws IOException {
        gui1 x = new gui1();
        setTitle(" ");
        setSize(1200,700);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b= new JButton("click");
        b1= new JButton();
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e0){    
                b1.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
                b.show(false);
                add(x);
            }       
        });
        b.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        add(b1);
        add(b);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        red k = new red();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui1 extends Canvas {

    public static Image p;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(p, 700, 200, 100, 100, this);
    }

    {
        try {
            p= ImageIO.read(new File("Lighthouse.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Wat do you mean with 'get' image? 'draw' image? What error messages do you see and under which conditions? ... Just looking at your code (ignoring the story) I see that you have no layout, and you don't specify the bounds of x, so it can never be visible.

Comment: but how can i put the Jbutton at the exact position i want and at the same time call the paint component>

Comment: Add `x.setBounds(.., ..., .., ...)` anywhere. Oh and x needs to be larger than 700x200 because you place the image that far from the upper-left corner of x.

Comment: i didnt understand it...could u give a little piece of the code

Comment: You want to do what, when? You know, you could just a `JLabel` to display an image, it would do the same thing, probably better

Comment: i want to call the picture on the class gui1 but i dont know how

Comment: @MadProgrammer could u be more specific cuz im new to java and im getting you

Comment: @rediramaj [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer but can i use a JLabel to put the image in the exact position that i wanted?

Comment: @rediramaj There are ways, but it depends on what you ultimately want to achieve.  In respect to your immediate question, simply create a new instance of `gui1` and add it to your `JFrame`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i thank you very much for your consideration but as i said im still a rookie.. what is an instance of gui1?

Comment: ...okay, so maybe you should reconsider starting with graphical interfaces until you've grasped some of the core concepts of the language, an "instance" describes when an `Class` is created in memory for you to use, `gui1 myGUI = new gui1();` will create an "instance" of the class and assign it to the variable `myGUI`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i dont know but if im not wrong i seem to have done that also to have added in my jframe

Comment: @rediramaj Give the fact that you've done away with the layout manager, you will need take over it's responsibility and size and position the component, you may also need to call `repaint` on the frame before it will update, remember, the image is already offset inside the component, so what ever position you provide the component, the image will be offset from that point

Comment: @MadProgrammer so there is smth that can be done or should i start writing it in a different way?

Comment: @rediramaj I'm thinking a layout manager is a good start, but that would all depend on your ultimate goal

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know a little bit with layouts....but when i input a layout, i dont know how to put the jbutton in the position i want :/

Comment: @rediramaj You need to stop thinking in terms of "pixels" and in terms of "relationship", for example, "I want the image to centered and the button to placed below it", this could be done with a `GridBagLayout` or `BorderLayout` depending on your needs

Answer (score 5):

Phew! I see **A LOT** of errors in your code (even after I corrected the compilation errors):

1. You're not following the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

   > Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized

   while `red` is a noun it should be more descriptive and be capitalized. The same goes for `gui1`
2. You're extending `JFrame` which in plain english would say: `red` **is a** `JFrame`, you should really avoid this and create your GUI based on `JPanel`s instead... see [Java Swing using extends JFrame vs callint it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252329/java-swing-using-extends-jframe-vs-calling-it-inside-of-class)
3. You're setting size (a REAAAAAAALLY big one window for the `JButton` sizes you're using), instead use [`pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack())
4. You're using `null-layout`, while pixel-perfect GUIs might seem like the easiest way to create complex GUIs for Swing newbies, the more you use them the more problems related to this you'll find in the future, they are hard to maintain and cause random problems, they don't resize, etc. Please read [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more information about why you should avoid its use and why you should change your GUI to work with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) along with [Empty Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for extra spacing between components.
5. You're making use of a deprecated method [`JFrame#show()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show(...)) you should be using [`JFrame#setVisible(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean)) instead.
6. Related to point #4, you shouldn't be calling `setBounds(...)` method, but let that calculations to the layout managers.
7. You're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), Swing is not thread safe, you can fix this by changing your `main()` method as follows:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Your constructor here
           }
       });
   }
   ```
8. You're mixing AWT and Swing components, instead of using AWT's [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) use Swing's [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) which has more functionality and support.
9. Images will become embedded resources once they're packaged in a JAR file, so it's wise to start treating them as if they already were, not as external files as shown in the <kbd>[embedded-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info)</kbd> tag.
10. Once you change from `Canvas` to `JPanel` you should override its [`paintComponent(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method and not [`paint(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) and call it's `super.paintComponent(g)` method as the first line, also don't forget to add the `@Overrides` annotation. See the [tutorial on Swing custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).
11. You're abusing the use of `static` keyword, see [how does the static keyword works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

After seeing all the above errors I recommend you to go back and [Learn the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) of the language before starting with a graphical environment which will only add more difficulty to your learning.

---

From what I understand you want to draw an image on a button click, if that's the case then you can wrap your image in a `JLabel` and add that `JLabel` to a `JPanel` which then is added to a parent `JPanel` which is later added to the `JFrame`:

[image]

As you can see in the GIF above, the icon is displayed after user presses the button.

Obviously this can be improved for the GUI to be more "attractive" with combinations of layout managers and empty borders as stated before.

This was done with the following code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageDrawingFromOneClassToAnother {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel pane;
    private JPanel leftPane;
    private JPanel rightPane;

    private ImageIcon icon;

    private JButton button;

    private JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageDrawingFromOneClassToAnother().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("king.png")); //Read images as if they were already embedded resources

        button = new JButton("Draw image");

        label = new JLabel(""); //Create an empty label

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setIcon(icon); //On button click, we set the icon for the empty label
            }
        });

        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200); //Set a size for the main panel
            }
        };

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); //The main panel

        leftPane = new JPanel(); //The button panel
        leftPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        leftPane.add(button);

        rightPane = new JPanel(); //The panel where the image will be drawn
        rightPane.add(label);

        //We add both (button and image) panels to the main panel
        pane.add(leftPane);
        pane.add(rightPane);

        frame.add(pane); //Add the main panel to the frame
        frame.pack(); //Calculate its preferred size
        frame.setVisible(true); //Set it to be visible
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```